# Why can't some user accounts access certain remote ports?

Tags: networking, iptables, redhat

I am trying to troubleshoot a couple issues on RHEL 6.5 that seem related.  In both cases, a user on a machine (seperate machines) cannot access a service (seperate services) on a remote machine.  In one case, a license server, in the other, a git server.  In both cases, a different user can log in and use the same exact command and have it succeed.  It is not a permissions issue on the remote machine (the git command, for example, works with the original users username and password on the server, but only if run from someone else's linux account).

To be more specific- User A is attempting to use an eclipse variant on machine B.  That variant is trying to hit a remote license server and failing.  If I log into the machine, I can run that eclipse and it hits the license server as expected.

A seperate user, User B was attempting

```
git clone http://UserB@servername/stash/project/repo.git
```

and got the error

```
Fatal: unable to access "http://UserB@ourserver/stash/project/repo.git": Failed to connect to ourserver:1080
```

Another user was standing there watching and entered su otherUser, then entered the same exact command and had it succeed.

The built in firewall according to system-config-firewall is disabled.  Is there a way to disable outgoing connections to ports for certain user accounts without using /etc/sysconfig/iptables? (since that doesn't exist at the moment?)

Comment: Try checking if selinux is enabled: "cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux" and also check the fw rules with "iptables -L".

Comment: selinux is enabled.  I am unfamiliar with this and am reading about it now.

Comment: Doesn't seem like `selinux` to me but, let's make sure. Trun it off and then test out the commands that failed before: `echo 0 | sudo tee /selinux/enforce`. To turn it back on after the test: `echo | sudo tee /selinux/enforce`

Comment: I'd start off running `strace` on these commands when they're failing.  Or see what `tcpdump` says.  When git fails, does raw SSH work?